# ghci : resume an interrupted task

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghci

in the emacs repl, I have ghci running.

if I hit C-c C-c, it interrupts some `forever` IO, and says

```
λ> server1
Listening on port 4444Accepted connection from localhost: 57441
Accepted connection from localhost: 57444
Accepted connection from localhost: 57447
Interrupted.
```

I can't find how to resume the program.

Comment: depending on your setup it will ask you again - if not kill the buffer and just reload your file into it (btw: working with haskell-mode?)

Comment: btw: if you are talking about your program (not ghci in the emacs repl) then just use `:main`

Comment: I don't believe it can be resumed, only restarted.

Comment: There were some blog posts a while back about setting up Haskell programs for CL-style runtime code replacement with GHCi. Serious ugly hackery there. I don't know if that code still works or if it's bit-rotted, but I'd be scared of it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments describe, you can't "resume" a task here. What happened is that you threw a signal, which was turned into a runtime exception. This exception terminated the thread. You can start a new task up again, but the thread didn't have a mechanism to "catch and suspend".

You could add such a mechanism -- for example to create your server thread as a separate thread along with a "resume" `MVar`, then then have it catch signals on exceptions, and then block on reading from the `MVar`.

Comment: thanks. I was wondering as I created a socket and the port was still unavailable after interrupting. it gave me the impression that I could resume the thread..